# floating action button is also scrolling along with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added a floating action button with `recyclerview` which is also scrolling along with the `recyclerview` my problem is that I have a bottom navigation in main activity so I'm trying to put my floating action button above bottom navigation which is in the main layout when my fragment is called but instead my fab is shown at the end of `recyclerview` and it is also scrolling along with the `recyclerview` how can I make it not scroll when the fragment is called in `MainActivity`.

Please any help would be appreciated

**My XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.fragments.FeedFragment">

    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Feed"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/feed_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"

        android:paddingTop="15dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`RelativeLayout`** as Root layout

And Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and 
            `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to attach your  **`FloatingActionButton`** at bottom of screen

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.fragments.FeedFragment">

            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Feed"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/feed_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"

                android:paddingTop="15dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should put floating action button outside of nested scrollview..